# Setting asynchronous value to a variable not working

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

First take a look at the code

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("CartItem").then(val => console.log(val))
```

When I run it, it logs this array of objects

```
[{"id":"6084844531f6aa1a980272e6","name":"Garlic","price":300,"qty":10,"totalPrice":3000,"image":"Some image"}]
```

I need that value which is returning from AsyncStorage to be assigned to a global variable like this

```
var cart
AsyncStorage.getItem("CartItem"). then(val => cart = val)
console.log(cart)
```

But the cart variable doesn't affect it logs `undefined`

It's a function in react-native not a component, so please don't say store the `val` to state

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The call made to AsyncStorage is obviously async. then block would be executed when the AsyncStorage get the value retrieved. Currently your system is busy in retrieving value but it goes to the next line before the value retrieves.

Following code should work

```
 var cart = await AsyncStorage.getItem("CartItem")
```